# Remove pages with redundant content from PDF document

Tags: pdf

I have a huge PDF document (several hundred pages) which was very likely produced from a PowerPoint presentation.

It contains one page per presentation step, so if on one PowerPoint slide there was some text or an image that appeared later with an animation, there will be two pages in the PDF: one with only the initial content of the slide and one with the animated object added.

I do not have access to the original presentation, only the PDF.

Now is there a way (script, application, ...) to automatically remove all redundant pages and only keep the last page with all information of each set of pages per original slide, discarding the incomplete pages with the animation steps?

The check algorithm would actually be quite simple: for each page, check whether the following page contains at least all information (text, images, objects) from the current page or more, and if so, remove the current page.

Unfortunately I have no idea whether or how it is possible to compare pages of PDF documents and find out whether the elements of one are a subset of the other or not.

Can you give me any solution that helps me to tidy up my huge PDF document and remove the animation steps in order to print it out?

**I do not really want a PDF editor application where I have to check and remove all the pages manually anyway, I already have https://www.xodo.com/ for that. What I hope for is a way to automate the process.**

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/)? You can invoke its various features [from the command line](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html). You can extract each page as text, use diff to see if each successive page has mostly additions to the previous one, keep track of the interesting pages, then use pdfbox again extract only those pages.

I assume from your rating that you don't need detailed instructions for how to accomplish all this :)

Comment: I think this would fail if the added content is an image, the two pages would have same text extracted.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but generally each Q&A here should be intended to be useful for every visitor, regardless of their knowledge. Therefore it's a good thing to talk to everybody as if they were five. Also if you are familiar with that tool, it's easier for you to quickly smash some working commands together that do at least roughly what the question wants than if I have to start reading the manual from zero... Depending on how much time your answer saves me, I might also possibly feel generous with a bounty, so that your efforts would be at least rewarded with some internet points.

Comment: I already pointed to the CLI commands that the tool authors have kindly provided.

Answer (score 2):

I exactly ran into need of same thing. So I created a Python Script that automates this checking & removal of pages with redundant content from PDF. Give it a check [here](https://github.com/jaladh-singhal/utiliPy-scripts/tree/master/PDF%20Trimmer).

This works well for repetitive text content, yet it may not keep the images if an animation on same slide replaces previous image - because I didn't needed that. If anyone finds a way, please let me know by opening a PR - I'll be happy to improve it.

PS: Thanks for your elaborated question! It helped me writing a nice readme for this script. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've written a CLI utility that removes the "animation" (step-by-step reveal) slides from a pdf.

- It takes a pdf file that was exported from a presentation.
- It detects the image difference between two consecutive pages (assuming white background).
- It omits a page if its consecutive page only enhances it.

Because it does image differences, it shouldn't matter if there are problems extracting the text or if the only difference between two consecutive slides is an image.

It's called `pdfdeanimate-image.py` and can be found in this MIT-licensed repo: https://github.com/schokotets/pdf-slides-utils - I'm open to pull requests, as the implementation isn't very clean so far.

I've copied the current python source code here. It requires `poppler-utils` for rendering the pdf and `pdftk` for concatenating the pdf. It creates a directory to store the `.pgm` files, which are grayscale slide renders.

Run it via: `./pdfdeanimate-image.py slides.pdf`.
The result is a file `stripped-slides.pdf`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env nix-shell
#!nix-shell -i python3 -p poppler_utils pdftk python38 python38Packages.numpy python38Packages.pillow

import subprocess
import sys
import os
import glob
import numpy
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

pdffile = sys.argv[1]
pdffile_name = pdffile.rsplit(".",1)[0]

pgmdir_name = pdffile_name+"-pgm"
pgmfile_name = pgmdir_name+"/"+pdffile_name

try:
    os.mkdir(pgmdir_name)
    subprocess.run(["pdftoppm", "-gray", pdffile, pgmfile_name])
    print("converted pdf to pgm files")
except FileExistsError:
    print("assuming pdf is already converted to pgm")


lastpix = None
haslastpix = False

containpages = []
currenthold = -1

filelist = glob.glob(os.path.join(pgmdir_name, '*.pgm'))
for filename in sorted(filelist, key=lambda s: s.lower()):
    pagenr = filename.rsplit("/",1)[-1].rsplit(".",1)[0].rsplit("-",1)[-1]

    img = Image.open(filename)
    pix = numpy.array(img)
    img.close()

    if haslastpix:
        isconsecutive = numpy.all(lastpix >= pix)
        if not isconsecutive:
            containpages.append(currenthold)

    lastpix = pix
    haslastpix = True
    currenthold = pagenr

containpages.append(currenthold)

print(f"reduced {len(filelist)}-pages pdf to {len(containpages)}-pages pdf")

subprocess.run(["pdftk", pdffile, "cat"] + containpages + ["output", "stripped-"+pdffile])
```

Answer (score 0):

A group of students at the TU Vienna wrote a web-based tool that removes duplicated slides from certain PDFs.
https://fsinf.github.io/pdf-page-stripper/

Depending on what you're looking for, one of the 4 different tools listed here might work best. Here is a quick overview of how each one works.

- [PDF Page Stripper](https://fsinf.github.io/pdf-page-stripper/): This one looks at the *page numbers*. A lot of exported PDFs will have the same page number for animated, duplicated slides. This makes removing the redundant ones quite easy.
- [PDF Trimmer by Jaladh Singhal](https://github.com/jaladh-singhal/utiliPy-scripts/tree/master/PDF%20Trimmer): It checks if consecutive pages have the same *text*. If so, it removes the previous, now redundant page.
- [pdfdeanimate-image by SchokoTets](https://github.com/schokotets/pdf-slides-utils): It checks if consecutive pages *look* the same, or rather if later pages only have additional, darker content. Then it removes the redundant ones.
- [Apache PDFBox®](https://pdfbox.apache.org/): This one is *not* an automated tool. Instead, it can be used as a CLI tool to extract text from PDFs. After that, one would have to manually compare and remove the redundant pages.